# cannot open output file , Permission denied error : Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

I have a problem in CodeBlocks. My 1st code was run, but if I run the same code again, I cannot see my output.

```
=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler unknown) ===
cannot open output file E:\PDF Files\C URI\hudai 33.exe Permission denied
error: ld returned 1 exit status
=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: You mean when compiling?

Comment: yes, first it compile, but when I again run it , it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're on Windows, and you're compiling a file named `hudai 33.exe`. The linker can't overwrite that file (`hudai 33.exe`), probably since it is still running.

You must stop running your new executable before compiling it again.

Comment: so, now what should I do  ??   I first uninstall the previous one, and download a new one and install it  !!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. And it was a bit difficult to solve because the message says that don't have permission to open the file. But the problem is that the program is still running.

If the program is still running I thought that I will find inside task manager, but wasn't there. So, I tried to delete the file and I wasn't able to delete too. Searching more about I find the program "Process Explorer". With this program I was able to see that my exe file is still running, but with a message saying that the program was suspended. Then I tried to kill through Process Explorer, but without success, because I still don't have permissions. So I open my CMD with right button, and choose EXECUTE LIKE A ADMINISTRATOR and then kill the proccess with the command taskkill /pid PIDNUMBER /T /F to kill the child proccess too.